# ffmpeg splitting video into hls slice, why hls_time option is not working?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

```
macbook:output developer$ ffmpeg -i ../output.mp4 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 1000000 index.m3u8
macbook:output developer$ 
macbook:output developer$ head index.m3u8 
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:3.136467,
index0.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
index1.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
index2.ts
macbook:output developer$
```

I want video slice with length around 1 second, but all I got `TARGETDURATION: 8` have you noticed that, where does it come from? I have not set anything like `8`, confusing... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segments will be cut at keyframes, so unless a keyframe exists each second, hls_time will not get honoured. Add `-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)` to add a keyframe at the start of each second.

Comment: thank you so much, I checked the option in the document which is not well organized,  $ ffmpeg -i ../output.mp4 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*1) index.m3u8
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(', is this because of version issue?

Comment: oh, I think double quote should be there, let me check

Comment: With double quote for expr statement works for me, without quotes is that ok for you?

Comment: Sure. It depends on which shell you're using

Comment: awesome, may I know what shell you are in, just curious